# why bootstrap result in overfitting for randomForest prediction?

Tags: r, random-forest, statistics-bootstrap

I am dealing with an imbalanced datasets with the R package randomForest. Some one has suggusted that, Bootstrap your data while over-sampling the rare class and under-sampling the common class. But I found that with the resampling size increasing, the OOB error decreasing to zero, which showd severe overfitting, I wonder why?
Actually this also happen with tree model(rpart).

Here is an example, althoug the data is balanced, just for testing of the effect of resample size:

```
require(randomForest)
set.seed(0)
iris500=iris[sample(1:nrow(iris),size=500,replace=TRUE),]
iris2000=iris[sample(1:nrow(iris),size=2000,replace=TRUE),]
formula="Species~Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width"
(rf0=randomForest(as.formula(formula),data=iris)) #OOB estimate of  error rate: 4%
(rf1=randomForest(as.formula(formula),data=iris500)) #OOB estimate of  error rate: 0.4%
(rf2=randomForest(as.formula(formula),data=iris2000)) #OOB estimate of  error rate: 0%

table(iris[["Species"]]) 
#setosa versicolor virginica 
#  50       50        50
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used to resample (augment) your rare class?  I would say that generally you should not be altering your data set too much, assuming that it reflects reality.

Comment: How many instances do you have in `iris`? Is it possible that the same instance exists in both training and testing set because of the resampling?

Comment: There is 50 instances for each class, may be that is a reason,but it did result a 100% accuracy.
if so, how should I balance my data through Bootstrap Resampling?

Comment: For the train-test manner of evaluating a model, you can first separate the dataset $$D$$  into a trainset $$D_{train}$$ and a testset $$D_{test}$$. Then you resample in the trainset $$D_{train}$$ to make a new trainset $$D'_{train}$$ and train on it to get a model. At last, you test your model on $$D_{test}$$